# The integral of a periodic function $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

Let $f$ be a periodic function that is positive and not equal to zero. Prove that

$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}\,dx$$

doesn't diverge.  Please help me find the answer.

Comment: When you say it isn't $y = 0$, do you mean that $f(x)$ is never zero, or that it isn't always zero?

Comment: Use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for future questions.

Comment: There is no symbol of integration so it is impossible to answer. Is it supposed to be $dx$ as Jack assumes?

Answer (score 3):

Through a suitable substitution we may assume, without loss of generality, that the given function is $1$-periodic. If $f(x)\geq K >0$ and $a\in\mathbb{N}$ we have

$$ \int_{2^a}^{2^{a+1}}\frac{f(x)}{x}\,dx \geq \int_{2^a}^{2^{a+1}}\frac{K}{x}\,dx = K\log(2) $$
hence
$$ \int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}\,dx = \int_{2^0}^{2^1}\frac{f(x)}{x}\,dx+\int_{2^1}^{2^2}\frac{f(x)}{x}\,dx+\int_{2^2}^{2^3}\frac{f(x)}{x}\,dx+\ldots$$
cannot be convergent.

Comment: And what if there is no such $K$? The periodicity guarantees one.

Comment: @mephistolotl: all right, I am going to improve that part.

Comment: @mephistolotl: no, wait, I am taking back that: the periodicity constraint does not ensure that $f$ is bounded, but in the worst case ($f$ not integrable over a period) we may take $K$ as any positive real number, and we still have divergence.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio consider the (non periodic) function $f(x)= 2^{-2a}x$ on the intervals $[2^a,2^{a+1}]$.

Comment: @Leo163: in such a case there is no positive constant $K$ that is a lower bound for $f(x)$ for any $x\in(1,+\infty)$.

Comment: Oh sorry. I did not see you edited the answer.